# Identify Deprecated Rules on Checkpoint Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, checkpoint

I've been asked to find the deprecated rules among the thousands of rules in our Checkpoint firewall.

I could do it by writing a perl program to analyze the log and lists of objects & rules, but i wanted to know if anybody knows of an easier way before reinventing the wheel.

I have access to SmartView Monitor et SmartView Tracker and i wanted to know if anybody knew of a way to achieve my goal with those tools.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to reinvent the wheel, I see only a paying solution.

You should take a look at SmartReporter, you need an additional license but I think Checkpoint can propose you a trial license.
You should also take a look to Eventia Reporter.